# Dates subtraction

Tags: date-and-time

I am interesting to calculate the time between a first event and last event.

I calculate this in following way:
The data looks as:

```
datesListEx = {"2014-12-08", "2014-01-14", "2014-05-30", "2014-11-13",
"2014-03-30", "2014-09-28", "2014-03-05", "2014-07-28", 
"2014-03-05", "2014-11-13", "2014-02-12", "2013-11-27", 
"2013-12-08", "2014-01-04", "2014-07-07", "2014-07-07", 
"2014-03-30", "2014-11-13", "2014-02-21", "2014-04-23", 
"2013-11-11", "2014-04-06", "2014-02-12", "2014-01-04", 
"2014-08-25", "2014-10-07", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-19", 
"2014-02-18", "2014-10-07", "2014-01-14", "2013-11-04", 
"2014-03-05", "2014-02-12", "2014-05-30", "2014-12-08", 
"2014-02-02", "2014-07-07", "2014-06-12"};
```

I sorted the data

```
datesListExSort = Sort@datesListEx;
```

And subtraction

```
 DateDifference[First[datesListExSort], Last[datesListExSort]]
```

I repeat the action thousands of times (with different data), the subtraction between dates that takes a lot of time. Is there a way to speed up this action?

Comment: You can convert to integers with `AbsoluteTime /@ datesListEx` and do computations and finally convert back with `DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] &`. (Documentation says "AbsoluteTime[] gives the total number of seconds since the beginning of January 1, 1900, in your time zone.")

Comment: Thank you. The convert to integers take more time than using DateDifference

        In[266]:= AbsoluteTime /@ datesListEx; // AbsoluteTiming

        Out[266]= {0.0176399, Null}
and  
    
     DateDifference[First[datesListExSort], 
     Last[datesListExSort]] // AbsoluteTiming

     Out[262]= {0.00331155, Quantity[399, "Days"]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edmund made a very good point. If your data strings are well-structured, you can load the data even faster with

```
dates2 = Map[
     DateObject[Join[#, {0, 0, 0}]] &,
     StringCases[datesListEx, s : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression[s]]
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00048

Compared to Edmund's solution:

```
dates1 = Map[
     DateObject[{#, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}}] &,
     datesListEx
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

dates1 == dates2
```

> 0.00806
>
> True

Answer (score 5):

If you are processing dates it is better to have them as [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html)s and use the functions in the [Date & Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html) guide.   Try converting to `DateObject`s when you import. Over a list of `DateObject`s named `dates` you will find `DateDifference @@ DateBounds@dates` to be very fast.

```
dates = DateObject[{#, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}}] & /@ datesListEx;
```

Then

```
RepeatedTiming[
 DateDifference @@ DateBounds@dates;
 ]
```

> ```
> {0.00085, Null}
> ```

versus

```
RepeatedTiming[
 datesListExSort = Sort@datesListEx;
 DateDifference[First[datesListExSort], Last[datesListExSort]];
 ]
```

> ```
> {0.0031, Null}
> ```

Hope this helps.